# Report Builder shows only one row

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I created a report with multiple DataSets. The first dataset contains adresses and the second contains contact data like phone and email.
So it is possible that a adress contains multiple contact items. But there is always only one contact item.
I've created a Matrix where the Adressdata is in it. In this matrix is another matrix, which should list all contact items. 
In both tables is a VaNr which is the Id for the adress.

EDIT:
I try to explain more details:
I have the the table Adress which looks like this
[image]

As you can see there are some easy adress-data and the VaNr.
John doe can have multiple contact data:

[image]

So in my report it should list john doe with three contacts. 
I grouped my adress list with the VaNr. 
[image]

The contact list for my adress is grouped to the VaNr:
[image]

But this is the result I get:
[image]

It only show one contact, but it should have three. There are three Contacts for John doe (with the same VaNr).

Comment: Looking at those images, you have groupings. Start there. Unfortunately there's little else I can offer, as the images themselves offer little more information, and I can't see your data, or the RDL file.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to show more details. It's difficult to show more. Maybe thsi edit helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, maybe it helps someone in future:

I had grouping everthing correctly. But to show the contact data I used the Lookup function. This shows only the first item of another DataSet.

`=Lookup(Fields!VaNr.Value, Fields!VaNr.Value, Fields!Contact.Value, "Contact")`

What I need is a list of all possible items in Contact. I had to change this expression like this:

`=Join(LookupSet(Fields!VaNr.Value, Fields!VaNr.Value, Fields!Contact.Value, "Contact"), Environment.NewLine)`

This returns a collection of Contact Items.

Comment: The lack of the ability to nest a tablix within another tablix that has another data source is one of SSRS's biggest shortcomings.  If MS could fix this, it would expand our ability to create reports using multiple disparate data sources.  LookUp is IMO, a sorry work around for something that should be as simple as nesting a tablix and then passing in a field from the parent to filter the child.

Comment: @FrankBall You describe exactly what my probelm is. I think this would make the report builder much better than know. Lookup is not a good solution, it's a bit hacky and not so clean. I hope they will change sometime.